# Who taught Kylo Ren to bleed his lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, kylo-ren

Who taught Kylo Ren how to [bleed](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bleeding) his lightsaber. Did he read about it in former Sith writings, did Snoke teach him (which seems possible but unlikely considering Snoke is not seen with a lightsaber of his own), or did Ren teach himself?

**Who taught Kylo Ren how to bleed his lightsaber?**

Comment: Don't assume that Snoke isn't proficient with or knowledgeable about lightsabers just because we don't see him use one. Remember that we never saw Palpatine use a lightsaber in the original trilogy, but the prequels showed he was obviously capable of using one.

Comment: I don't think we have an answer yet, but I am looking forward to the Resistance Era comics that are coming out next summer, as Kylo Ren and Snoke each have their own issues. I'm curious too if the method is the exact same as we are seeing in Darth Vader 2017+ comics, since Kylo Ren and Snoke aren't "Sith". Anyways interesting Star Wars Q!

Comment: Boolean - where did you read or see the "bleeding" of the lightsaber?

Comment: What does it mean to "bleed" a lightsaber? I assume that's an expanded universe concept?

Comment: @Sam [lightsaber bleeding](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bleeding)

Comment: These lightsabers don't bleed.

Comment: @RobertColumbia The kyber crystals are bleed to turn them red. It is featured in the current running Darth Vader comic series which takes place starting from the end of RotS and tells the story of how Anakin continues to transform into Darth Vader and is now getting into the building and backstory behind Vader's castle. But Vader had to hunt down and kill a Jedi, steal his lightsaber kyber crystal, bleed it red (ie: cause the crystal to suffer), and then take it for his own...

Comment: @Thunderforge - it's canon. First mentioned in the 'Ashoka' novel

Comment: Is this the *only* way the Sith get their red lightsabers?  In earlier canon they used [synthetic kyber crystals](https://vulkk.com/2016/02/18/origins-of-unstable-lightsaber-crystal-star-wars-lore/), which were red, because they didn't have easy access to real ones.  Maybe Kylo uses one?

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet - No, synthetic lightsaber crystals in the new canon are different.

Comment: Possibly, Snoke..

Answer (score 7):

### From what we know, probably no one

Kylo Ren used ancient design for [his lightsaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kylo_Ren%27s_lightsaber), back from the time of [Great Scourge of Malachor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Scourge_of_Malachor). Kyber crystal in it was cracked, so excess heat was vented to sides as crossguard.

This of course begs the question why would he use cracked crystal. Kyber crystals were rare, but not that rare (Death Stars required lots of them for main weapon) . Before joining Snoke Kylo was training as a Jedi, so he probably had lighstaber with normal crystal. Also, First Order was not exactly without resources, they in fact built [Starkiller Base](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starkiller_Base) on a planet rich with kyber crystals.

More likely reason is that Snoke didn't know, or didn't want to show Kylo Ren how to bleed crystals. Therefore, Kylo searched Sith artifacts (maybe even on Malachor) to find both designs and the crystal. If he was really on Malachor, he could have picked defunct weapon like Ezra Bridger did (only Kylo would probably take Sith weapon).

[image]

So, instead of creating his own, Kylo used crystal that belonged to someone else and was damaged long time ago. Final note, bleeding crystals is not that easy, as Vader found out.

[image]